# How to log exceptions only to a specific logger in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a `log4j2` configuration to Sysout everything to console + log general content to a `application.log` file + log any exceptions to an `error.log` file.

Problem: errors are logged in both application + error log file.

`org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.error("Exception log", ex);`

What might be missing in the following configuration?

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CMD" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="APPLICATION" fileName="application.log">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="ERR" fileName="error.log">
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="CMD" />
            <AppenderRef ref="APPLICATION" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ERR" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK one has to combine multiple `ThresholdFilters` for it:

```
<RollingFile name="APPLICATION" fileName="application.log">
    <Filters>
        <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    </Filters>
</RollingFile>
```